# Problema na formatação de CSS

Tags: css, div

Nobres amigos,

Estou trabalhando em um ebook no programa Sigil. Ao linkar a folha de estilos css ao xhtml eu consigo formatar as tags h1, h2 e h3. No entanto, no mesmo arquivo, eu não consigo formatar as tags p e div. Já observei a nomenclatura e não consegui encontar o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Qual seletor voce esta utilizando? Observe que alguns seletores sao mais fortes que outros e por isso se voce tentar mudar o estilo utilizando um seletor mais fraco nao ira funcionar, tente colocar `!important` depois de cada propriedade css que voce quiser editar para resolver isso.

Comment: Vilson, acontece que eu estou copiando as mesmas regras que eu já havia usado em outro ebook. Agora simplesmente não funciona.

Comment: poderia postar link para o projeto ou colocar parte do css e do html?

Comment: h1 {

font-family: arial, "times new roman", georgia, serif;
color: black;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 2em;
margin-top: 3em;

Comment: p {

font-family: arial, "times new roman", georgia, serif;
text-align: justify;
font-size: 1.1em;
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
text-indent: 1em;
}

Comment: A tag h1 funciona. A tag p não.

Comment: usa bootstrap, ou algum css de terceiros, ou normalize?

Comment: tenta apagando o cache, ctrl+f5 no navegador

Comment: Estou usando o Sigil para fazer um ebook. Você acha que o ctrl+f5 irá influir?

Comment: eu nao sei nem o que e isso, tambem sou ruim em css.

Comment: Você acredita que o bootstrap é melhor para construir ebooks do que o Sigil?

Comment: tu tentou com !important?

Comment: quanto a sigil ou bootstrap se eu fosse voce eu nao usaria nenhum, tive muitos problemas usando frameworks que prometiam fazer magica mas na verdade so complicam as coisas.

Comment: Mas como fazer um ebook sem usar um programa desse tipo? Será que o WebStorm pode ajudar?

Comment: outra coisa eu nao sei o quanto voce conhece css, mas duvido que saiba o suficiente, css e facil e esse e o problema por ser facil a gente acaba pensando que ja domina, tente estudar mais css.

Comment: a forma mais facil e javascript, javascript e bem mais facil que css, pode usar a tag canvas